# Images auto resize with screen height, no scrollbar - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Two days have been passed with it. But I didn't found any solution yet. *Conditions is*-

**1. No scrollbar (vertical or horizontal)**,

**2. Screen height is unknown, so all content (images and text) should be auto-resize with screen height,**

My code is here-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML Quickstart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Bootstrap fremwork main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        #padding{
            padding: 15px;
        }
        img{
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myDiv">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="padding">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dignissimosus.</h2></div>
            </div>

        </div>  <!-- end container -->
    </div> <!-- end myDiv -->

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried with this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=adapt%20screen%20height%20no%20scrollbar%20css&oq=adapt%20screen%20height%20no%20scrollbar%20css&aqs=chrome..69i57.13566j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=images%20auto%20resize%20with%20screen%20height%20no%20scrollbar%20css&*) and [it](https://www.google.com/search?q=adapt%20screen%20height%20no%20scrollbar%20css&oq=adapt%20screen%20height&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60.12983j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Since content (not many contents) is large than screen height, so is it possible to adapt screen height?

Please write a comment if you've any solution, suggestion or anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been tried many times like as-

`html{
 height:100%;
}
body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0px;
}

.myDiv{
 float:left;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: well if you want to disable the scrollbar then use `img { overlay-x: hidden }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your webpage fully responsive, you should follow [the Grid System Of Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) rules. 
Here are some Grid Options you could use.

[image]

I have also provided you the source code & demo how your case should be done. You should learn and take advantage more from it. Hope this answer yours. *Feel free to ask me bro*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .row {
      margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    }
    
    .picture {
      padding: 0.3em;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 picture">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dignissimosus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment bro. It's not a responsive or fully responsive issue. It's adapt scrollbar issue. Content should adjust with screen height, without any scrollbar.

Comment: You are welcome. I was thinking you want your page fully responsive in any devices such as smartphone, tablet, laptop, and pc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex box for layout. I've removed Bootstrap grid code to avoid confliction. Also, id `padding` is used multiple times, which is fixed in below  code too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML Quickstart</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <!-- Bootstrap fremwork main css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
    html, body, .myDiv, .container {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container .image {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .container .image img {
      flex: 1;
    }
    .padding{
      padding: 15px;
      flex: 1;
    }
    img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100% !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row image">
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row image">
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row image">
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text">
      <div class="col-md-12"><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dignissimosus.</h2></div>
    </div>

  </div>  <!-- end container -->
</div> <!-- end myDiv -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Your answer is working, but looking forward to a more suitable answer.